# iOS App crashes showing Variable is not a CFArray

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I am using the below code to retrieve data from web services coming in JSON format

```
NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
NSDictionary *responseDict = [responseString JSONValue];   
NSMutableDictionary *statusDict = [responseDict objectForKey:@"body"];
NSArray *arrayPickListValue = [statusDict objectForKey:@"ticketEntries"];
```

sometimes data is coming in arrayPickListValue and showing the content on iPhone, however sometimes if ticketEntries key is Null , it is showing Variable is not a CFArray, so how do i solve with this issues

Comment: You should check ticketEntries and put it into arrayPickListValue only if it is NOT null...

Comment: Ok but how we will check with ticketEntries, its a key inside body where content is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Beppe said, you need to check it first:

```
// check whether it is NULL or not first
id arrayPickListValue = [statusDict objectForKey:@"ticketEntries"];
if ([arrayPickListValue isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
    // manage the error
    return;
}

// do work
```

Comment: Hey Beppe thanks for the reply and Kjuly i have resolved the issue by self, thanks for the reply once again, i will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if([[statusDict objectForKey:@"ticketEntries"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
 {
    //is array
    NSArray *arrayPickListValue = [statusDict objectForKey:@"ticketEntries"];
 }
 else  
 {
    //not a array
    //manage here as it might is null.

 }
```